# Selecting records monthly based on date of month user signed up

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I need to figure out a way either in MySQL or programmatically (ColdFusion but the logic isn't language specific) to pull out all user records based on the day of the month they signed up, each month.

For example, on 2-5-15 I want to select all users who signed up on the 4th of any month and any year - 1-4-15, 12-4-15, 1-4-14 etc.

Probably arises on the 1st day of each month.  So on 3-1, I need to get the users for 2-28, but also 1-28,1-29,1-30 and 1-31, and same for Dec, and November needs to 11-28, 11-29, 11-30 etc.

Simple solution would be to run the process on the 1st of each month just getting everyone from the previous month period, but I'd like to explore running it daily selecting previous dates.

[edit] I'm thinking along the lines of something like this.  If the run date is the 1st of the month, figure out how many days were in the previous month.  If it's 31, no problem.  If it's 30, I need to get all 30s and 31s from all previous months/year.  If it's 28, then I need to get the 28s, 29s, 30s, and 31s. I think this logic holds up...

[edit 2] here's some pseudo code that I think works.

```
set runDate = '2015-03-01'
if day(runDate) = '01'
  set daysLastMonth = days in previous month (28)
  loop from daysLastMonth to 31 index = i
    query all records where day(addDate) = i
  endloop
else
  query all records where day(addDate) = day(runDate)-1
endif
```

Comment: This can be purely handled at DB end and then brought to front end in CF, if reqd.

Comment: I updated on one path of thinking that I've been working on this morning.

Comment: @Steve - Not sure I follow the question...  The above seems to describe *how* you are trying to approach your task without fully defining what that task is first.  Exactly what are you trying to do in plain English, not psuedo code? For example, ie "On the first of every month, I want to retrieve the users that signed up on the previous "day" (or previous X days) - in any year?

Comment: On any given day, get users that signed up on that day from any month any year.  I.e. on the 15th, I want all users who signed up on the 15th of any month / any year.  It's simple until you get to the end of the month.  For example, if it runs on 11/30, I can get all "30s" easily enough, but since there is no 11/31, I'd miss users who signed up on any 31st.  Last day of Feb is (usually) 28th, and next day is 3/1, so I'd miss anyone who signed up on the 29th, 30th, 31st of any month.

Comment: That does not sound right, not unless you have some additional business rules you not have explained.  That logic might count some days twice, and omit others. If you are simply trying to count the number of users that signed up on the previous *day*, use calendar functions to figure out what that "day" is with regard to the various months. Unless there are some special business rules you need to apply, using calendar functions is simpler, and more reliable than trying to roll your own date functions.

Comment: Everyone should have 12 "transactions" per year.  If I do yesterday, and your monthly date is the 30th, you'd be skipped for February because yesterday from March 1 is Feb 28 (or 29).  Maybe I didn't explain the rules clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Mysql has a dayofmonth() function, but using functions to filter data tends to be slow.  That being the case, you might be better off using ColdFusion to create a list of dates.  Something like this:

```
dayInQuestion = CreateDate(2015,1,1);
dayOfMonthYouWant = Day(DateAdd("d", -1, dayInQuestion));
dateYouWant = CreateDate(2011, 1, dayOfMonthYouWant);
listOfDates = "";
while (dateYouWant < dayInQuestion) {
listOfDates = ListAppend(listOfDates, dateYouWant);
dateYouWant = DateAdd("m", 1, dateYouWant);
}
```

Then, your query would include this:

```
where yourDateField in (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" 
value="#ListOfDates#" list="yes">)
```

Note that this is just a starting point.  Depending on how far back you want to go, you might run into problems with the list being too long.

In fact, you might even want to try the mysql dayofmonth().  Maybe it's fast enough for your application.

**Edit begins here**

Here is another approach that you should consider if your date data includes the time of day.

```
dayInQuestion = CreateDate(2015,1,1);
queryDate = CreateDate(someYear, month(dayInQuestion), day(dayInQuestion);
```

then make your query resemble this:

```
where 1 = 2
<cfloop condition = "queryDate lt dayInQuestion">
or (
yourDateField >= #dateadd("d", -1, queryDate)#
and yourDateField < #queryDate# )
<cfset queryDate = DateAdd("d", 1, queryDate)>
</cfloop>
```

but with query parameters of course.

Comment: Interesting.  Similar to what I pseudocoded above, but instead of your list I did a loop with from 1-4 iterations max if it was the 1st of any month.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT *
FROM USERS
WHERE MONTH(REG_DATE) = MONTH(NOW()) - 1;
```

Where now is the current date or any specific date you can supply.

Comment: That works if I want to run the process once per month.  Running today gets me all users from any January.  Running tomorrow gets me the same thing.